# What is the best pattern for responding to React state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Often in React, I will call `setState` and then want to do something once the state is updated.

So far, I am familiar with 2 patterns to *do something once the state is updated*

**Pattern 1: Set State Callback**

`setState({property: newValue}, () => /* do something after the state is updated  */)`

To me, this pattern seems pretty reasonable. However, its use seems to be generally discouraged by the React community. Additionally, React Hooks don't support this pattern at all.

**Pattern 2: Component Did Update**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if(prevProps.property !== this.props.property){
      /* do something after the state is updated  */
   }
}
```

I have a few problems with this pattern

1. When you need to respond to **many** different state changes, your componentDidMount ends up having TONS of these if statements to correspond to a given state change. (IN one component, I have nearly 20.
2. It can be VERY tricky to write all these different if statements in such a way that they don't overlap or crash into each other, or conflict in any way. I end up spending a bunch of time making sure that the logic of all these if statements is correct.

In conclusion, this pattern just seems to make VERY complex. Because not only do I have to set the state, but I then have to identify exactly how to identify that specific state change, while avoiding conflicts with `n` other if statements.

**My Question:**

Is there better pattern for handling this? Neither of these options seem **even close to promising**, and I am curious what is recommended.

Comment: "*[...] its use seems to be generally discouraged by the React community*" - it is? I've used that pattern for handling updates to state for a while now. What's the issue with that approach?

Comment: @TimLewis Wanted to ask same thing, what's wrong with setState callback?

Comment: Stuff like this gives me that impression 
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2642#issuecomment-66676469

Comment: That comment is 5 years old...

Comment: Additionally callbacks seem like a bit of a dated paradigm. And since there are no clear movements to update it (with promises for example) it seems like it is moving towards a deprecated status.

And then of course, the whole not being used in React hooks issue.